# ReactJs , DOM does not get updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the following code:

```
componentDidUpdate(){
    let self = this;
    this.state.carsOfChoosenDriver = []; // array where I want to save the cars belonging to the choosenDriver

    if (typeof this.state.choosenDriver.cars !== 'undefined'){

      this.state.choosenDriver.cars.forEach(function(entry) {
         request
            .get('api/cars/' + entry)
            .end(function(err, res){
              self.state.carsOfChoosenDriver.push(res.body);
               console.log(self.state.carsOfChoosenEvent);
            });
    });
  }
}

handleEventClick(i){
  this.setState({choosenDriver: this.state.drivers[i]});
}
```

I choose a driver from a list which triggers `handleEventClick()`.
`choosenDriver.cars` contains an Array of id´s which I use to get the car-object from the db. This all works and the `res` gets logged in the console.

But the dom does not get updated on the first click on `handleEventClick()`.

In the render-method I have this:

```
  render() {

    let cars = this.state.carsOfChoosenDriver.map(function(car, i){
    return <li key={i}>{car.name}</li>;
  });
    return (

         <div className="col-md-8">
           {cars}
         </div>

    );
  }
```

Should I maybe use Another lifecycle-method or what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

```
componentDidMount() {
  let self = this;
    request
       .get('api/driver')
       .end(function(err, res){
        self.setState({drivers: res.body});
       });

}
```

Comment: Can you check if `render()` is called upon the first `handleEventClick()`? If not, it's likely an issue with `shouldComponentUpdate()` lifecycle-method

Comment: yes, by adding an alert in the render-method I can see that it is called BEFORE the logging-stuff that goes on in componentDidUpdate

Answer (score 0):

You should have the code in `componentDidUpdate` moved to `componentWillUpdate` instead.

`componentDidUpdate` is called after `render()` finishes flushing all the DOM updates, which isn't what you want as you would like to reflect the state changes caused by `handleEventClick(i)`

`componentWillUpdate` is called before `render()`, which **WILL** have the `self.state.carsOfChoosenDriver` change completed before `render()` is triggered.

Also, you should use `setState` instead of manually modifying the component states, which doesn't trigger `render()`.

```
.end(function(err, res){
  self.state.carsOfChoosenDriver.push(res.body);
  console.log(self.state.carsOfChoosenEvent);
});
```

Try use `setState`

```
.end(function(err, res){
  self.setState({carsOfChoosenDriver: res.body});
  console.log(self.state.carsOfChoosenEvent);
});
```

Because `setState` in React is async, but it triggers `render()`, and `render()` will wait for the async to finish before flushing DOM.

Comment: thank you but it does not work. When using componentWillUpdate, not even the console logs anything on the first click,

Comment: What does your `componentDidMount` or `componentWillMount` look like?

Comment: I added an update to the question. I componentDidMount I call the DB and gets all drivers.

Comment: I have a feeling you shouldn't modify the `self.state.carsOfChoosenDriver` manually, and you should use setState instead. for `self.state.carsOfChoosenDriver.push(res.body);
               console.log(self.state.carsOfChoosenEvent);` Try use `setState`. Because `setState` in React is async, but render() will wait for the async to finish before flushing DOM.

Comment: Thank you, the problem with Calling setState in componentDidUpdate is that setState calls componentDidUpdate and thus creating an infinite loop.

Comment: You should always only modify `states` in life-cycle events before `render()`. You can modify the `shouldComponentUpdate` to avoid infinite loops but it's not a recommended pattern. Glad you've caught it :)

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I am being unclear, but it still does not work. But I thank you for helping. =)